# Can we launch intern Script on already started IOS simulator

Tags: ios, appium-ios, intern

I am trying to run Intern.js scripts on IOS simulator.
we specify the device details in intern.js and that specified device gets automatically launched when we start the script execution.
I want to know is there any way to launch intern script on the already launched device (open simulator command)

I want to do some setup on a simulator before starting the script.

Answer (score 0):

Add a [noReset capability](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) to your environment descriptor:

```
{
  "platform": "iOS",
  "deviceName": "iPhone 8",
  "noReset": true,
  ...
}
```

This should tell Appium to use an open simulator rather than initializing a new one.